# KeyError: "Couldn't find field google.protobuf.DescriptorProto.ExtensionRange.options"

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda, tensorboard

How should I fix this error?

```
Mon Nov 13 00:37:49 :~$  /Users/mona/anaconda/bin/pip  install --upgrade tensorflow tensorflow-tensorboard
Collecting tensorflow
  Downloading tensorflow-1.4.0-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl (39.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 39.3MB 28kB/s
Collecting tensorflow-tensorboard
  Downloading tensorflow_tensorboard-0.1.8-py3-none-any.whl (1.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.6MB 560kB/s
Collecting wheel>=0.26 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading wheel-0.30.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 604kB/s
Collecting protobuf>=3.3.0 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading protobuf-3.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (375kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 378kB 57kB/s
Collecting numpy>=1.12.1 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading numpy-1.13.3-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (4.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 4.6MB 200kB/s
Collecting enum34>=1.1.6 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading enum34-1.1.6-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.10.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: werkzeug>=0.11.10 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow-tensorboard)
Requirement already up-to-date: bleach==1.5.0 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow-tensorboard)
Requirement already up-to-date: markdown>=2.6.8 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow-tensorboard)
Requirement already up-to-date: html5lib==0.9999999 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow-tensorboard)
Collecting setuptools (from protobuf>=3.3.0->tensorflow)
  Downloading setuptools-36.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (482kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 491kB 883kB/s
Installing collected packages: wheel, six, setuptools, protobuf, numpy, tensorflow-tensorboard, enum34, tensorflow
  Found existing installation: wheel 0.29.0
    Uninstalling wheel-0.29.0:
      Successfully uninstalled wheel-0.29.0
  Found existing installation: six 1.10.0
    Uninstalling six-1.10.0:
      Successfully uninstalled six-1.10.0
  Found existing installation: setuptools 36.5.0.post20170921
    Uninstalling setuptools-36.5.0.post20170921:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-36.5.0.post20170921
  Found existing installation: protobuf 3.3.2
    Uninstalling protobuf-3.3.2:
      Successfully uninstalled protobuf-3.3.2
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.12.1
    Uninstalling numpy-1.12.1:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.12.1
  Found existing installation: tensorflow 1.1.0
    Uninstalling tensorflow-1.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled tensorflow-1.1.0
Successfully installed enum34-1.1.6 numpy-1.13.3 protobuf-3.4.0 setuptools-36.7.1 six-1.11.0 tensorflow-1.4.0 tensorflow-tensorboard-0.1.8 wheel-0.30.0
Mon Nov 13 00:40:10 :~$ tensorboard --logdir=/var/folders/bk/2b2d879912bgnl5s768s7crh0000gn/T/tmpzy0cj6xc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mona/anaconda/bin/tensorboard", line 7, in <module>
    from tensorboard.main import main
  File "/Users/mona/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/main.py", line 29, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/Users/mona/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Users/mona/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/Users/mona/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 10, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor_pb2
  File "/Users/mona/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor_pb2.py", line 409, in <module>
    options=None),
  File "/Users/mona/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 501, in __new__
    return _message.default_pool.FindFieldByName(full_name)
KeyError: "Couldn't find field google.protobuf.DescriptorProto.ExtensionRange.options"
Mon Nov 13 00:40:22 :~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A related bug report on Google protobuf can be found [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/3631), you may want to check it out. There's a bug report on GitHub tensorflow [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12326). The solution may be to run

```
pip install tensorflow tensorflow-tensorboard --upgrade --force-reinstall
```

Can you try that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this recipe:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow
pip uninstall protobuf
pip install protobuf==3.3.0.
```

It works for me.